# Launching Zend results in a 503 error in the browser

Tags: apache, zend-framework, http-status-code-503

After installing Zend I try to launch it in the browser, either by opening the Zend application or by typing localhost:10081/ZendServer/ into the browser. Both attempts result in a 503 server error.
After some research I found that uninstalling Zend via terminal and reinstalling will solve the issue, but this didn't work.

I've also tried launching Zend, MySQL and the Apache server using terminal but these haven't helped.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.11.1 (I've tried the PHP 5.5 and 5.6 downloads).

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to launch a zend application you should set a 'VIRTUAL HOST'...
search for setting virtual host on you machine.
here is the way in Ubunto:
[How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

and here is for windows:[Creating virtual hosts on Apache](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache_vhosts.php)

Comment: Why is that not part of the installation instructions for ZendServer then?

Comment: @KevinM well ,its is known that Zend does not have a very strong documentation